# Themosis Framework for Wordpress: Template Routing

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the **Themosis** framework for Wordpress and am trying to figure out how to use the template routing.

I'm basing this off of the [routing docs](http://framework.themosis.com/docs/routing/)

The template slug is set in the *app/config/templates-config.php*:

```
return array(

    /*
    * Edit this file in order to configure your page
    * templates.
    *
    * Simply define a template slug.
    */

    'custom-template'

);
```

Then I set the following in the *routes.php*:

```
Route::get('template', array('custom-template', function(){

    return 'This will handle the custom-template slug...';

}));
```

But that just gets me a 404 error when I go to domain.dev/custom-template.  Not sure how to make it work so that I can set up a custom template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The templates defined inside the `templates.config.php` file are WordPress page templates. This means that you have to create a page, from WordPress admin, and assign your `custom-template` to that page.

So if you create a page with a title of `About Us`, the page URI is `about-us`. Assign the `custom-template` to your page from the `Templates` metabox (or Themosis Templates depending on your version) and visit the address at "http://yourdomain.com/about-us/" => This triggers the template route you defined.

So this route is called for all pages that have the `custom-template` assigned to them. The template slugs won't create any URI segments.